# R var predict requires both exogenous variable list and dummy variable list, what if my specification does not include dummy variables?

Tags: r, var, predict, dummy-variable

I am developing a Vector Auto Regression (VAR) time series model in R. The model specification includes a matrix (`xts` class) of endogenous variables called "endog," and a matrix (also `xts` class) of exogenous variables called "exog." The data are seasonal and I want the seasonality predicted, so I also specify "season = 12," since the data are monthly. So my R code to execute the var model is:

```
fit <- var(endog, p = 1, season = 12, type = 'const', exogen = exog)
```

This code runs smoothly. But now I want to predict the data for 24 periods ahead. So my predict code is:

```
predictions <- predict(fit, exo.fcst = exog_future, n.ahead = 24, ci = 0.95)
```

where "exog_future" is a matrix (also `xts` class) of the same variables as in exog, but includes the 24 future periods to be forecasted. (I tried two versions: one with the historical data exog plus the new data for the next 24 periods, and the other version includes just the 24 periods.)

I receive the following error message:

> Error in predict.varest(VAR(endog, p = 1, season = 12, type = "const",  : 
>   No matrix for dumvar supplied, but object varest contains exogenous variables.

Clearly, R expects a matrix of dummy variables in addition to exogenous variables. Unless R considers the "season = 12" specification as a matrix of dummy variables, the model specification includes no dummy variables, so why does it expect dummy variables now? In case it does consider the seasonal specification as dummy variables, I then added "season = 12, " to my predict code. I received the same error message.

I understand that if the model includes exogenous variables, then I must supply the future values for these in the predict code. I also understand that if I supplied dummy variables, that predict would need the future values of these as well for essentially the same reason. They are exogenous variables, just binary ones.

So, when the model specification does not include dummy variables, what is R expecting me to supply for "dumvar?"

Comment: I may have figured it out, but the solution is illogical. Perhaps someone could verify if the solution is correct.

Comment: I may have figured it out, but the solution is illogical. Perhaps someone could verify if the solution is correct. When I submit the matrix of future exogenous variables as _dumbvar = matrix_of_future_exogenous_variables_ the error goes away. It makes logical sense to submit these variables because the prediction needs their values to calculate the forecasted values of the endogenous variables. It makes no sense to call them _dumbvar_ because they are not binary. They are continuous variables, such as the _unemployment_rate_ .  Note, the matrix is in xts format, since this is time series.

Comment: Sorry for the duplication. I tried to edit immediately, but the system would not allow this because I took more than 5 minutes to complete my edit. Perhaps that limitation could be removed on a site that encourages thoughtful solutions.

Comment: What do you mean `I submit the matrix of future exogenous variables as dumbvar = matrix_of_future_exogenous_variables`. I have a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764339/how-to-predict-using-var-with-exogenous-variables-in-r ,  maybe you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Indeed when you have an exogenous value in your training, you have to include the future exogenous values `exog_future` as the parameter for `dumvar` in the function `predict()`, in your case you should set `dumvar=exog_future` so that

`predictions <- predict(fit, dumvar = exog_future, n.ahead = 24, ci = 0.95)`

In the R documentation http://127.0.0.1:26594/library/vars/html/predict.html it says that the main arguments of the function `predict()` are `object`, `n.ahead`,`ci` and `dumvar`, so in order to avoid confusion maybe you should ignore the argument `exo.fcst`. It is confusing because it seems that `exo.fcst` is the correct parameter for `exog_future` but in practice you should always use `dumvar` for this, not `exo.fcst`.